# Order of stages in Dockerfile for .NET Core

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile

Being fairly new to Docker, I'm currently reading several tutorials and there are two things I don't really understand. According to the official [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/samples/dotnetcore/), the Dockerfile could look like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY ../engine/examples ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

The first stage is to import the sdk and the second is to import the dotnet runtime. However, in other tutorials, e.g. [this one from Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotnet/guide/tutorials/docker-dotnet/aspnet-development-docker/), the order is reversed; first the runtime is imported and subsequently the sdk is imported.

First question; is there a preferred order of the imports (and why)?

Second question, in the example above, the csproj is first copied, `dotnet restore` is run, and then all other files are copied before building the application. Why not just copy everything at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way they're structured has a lot to do with maximizing the use of cached layers from previous builds to make the build go faster and using a runtime base image that's smaller that a full SDK image.

If you don't care about the build speed and image size, you can do something really simple like

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -o out
WORKDIR /src/out
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

This Dockerfile will have to build everything every time you change a file. You can speed up the restore of Nuget packages by realising that you rarely change the .csproj file.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
WORKDIR /src
COPY aspnetapp.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -o out
WORKDIR /src/out
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

Now when you just change some code (but not the .csproj file), Docker will see that up until `COPY . .` everything is the same as when you last ran `docker build`, so it'll just take the layers from the cache and you won't have to actually run the `dotnet restore` saving you some time.

To save some space on the final image, we can use the `aspnet` image as the base, rather than the `sdk` image. To do that we can use a *multistage Dockerfile* and copy files from the first stage to the last (and final) stage like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY aspnetapp.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /src/out /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

Now the final image is smaller, so it takes up fewer resources when we run it.

Comment: Okay, so to minimize the size of the final image, I should use a multistage Dockerfile where one stage uses the SDK and the other the runtime, but does the order matter? One option is `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 as base` .... `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 as build` and the other is `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build` ... `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0`.

Comment: For size considerations, it's only important that the `aspnet` image is the last image. The Jetbrains Dockerfile does some preparation on it in the first step and names it `base`. Then the final stage uses `FROM base` to continue working on it. The rest of the Dockerfile is about maximizing cache reuse, i.e. having steps that rarely change at the top of the Dockerfile.